# Is there MAX function for rows - not for columns?

Tags: mysql

I need to get maximum value of certain number of columns (for each row). Is this possible to do in MySQL?

For example:`SELECT MAX(column1, column2, column3)`.

**I'm not looking for MAX function that aggregates values of a given column. I need to aggregate values of different columns for each row.**

Comment: Can you please give a table structure or a basic idea of what you need specifically?

Comment: As Martin Smith said, the GREATEST() function. But if you're returning different columns from each row, you might have a structural problem that a higher normal form would solve in a better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function

```
SELECT GREATEST(column1, column2, column3) AS X
```

Comment: @Harry - Yep fixed to reference 5.6 now. For some reason 5.0 always comes up first in the google results.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT GREATEST(column1, column2, column3) as max_value`